# how to disable comments for wall-posts on fanpage/businesspage?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

for fanpages/businesspages:i know i can prevent users from posting new posts - but how can i prevent them from commenting existing posts ?

i create a fan-pages of a sportsclub. the page only has a wall - where all posts come via RSS Grafitti from a RSS feed.
it's just a way of spreading news - the sports club does not want any comments - since there's nobody who has the time to moderate this posts.

any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Not programming related post. Should not be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "People can write or post content on the wall" page setting (https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id={PAGEID}&sk=permissions). And have the page admin post the content.

Comment: Hello, that's what i'm doing! i have "People can write or post content to the wall" OFF.
The posts come via RSS Graffiti - but i just tried to do a normal posts (as admin) - it's the same result: the users can't create a new post - but they can comment a existing one (created by admin or RSS grafitti)

Comment: Then that should be filed as a bug with Facebook since you clearly have that option turn on so user cannot post or write content to the wall.  Http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.  Let us know what the bug # is.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this issue myself and the best I could find was a reference to "whitelisting" on this page: [Link](http://www.seoinc.com/seo-blog/how-to-moderate-facebook-comments-on-a-business-page/)

But there are no further instructions on who to reach at Facebook to get your page "whitelisted". I posted in the Community Forum but have not received an answer yet.